# *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop

Tags: unix, makefile

All I want to do, is change working directory to "initialization" and compile my program (at first).

```
OBJS = main.o create_queue.o
SOURCE = main.c create_queue.c
HEADER = create_queue.h
OUT = initialization
CC = gcc
FLAGS = -g -c
LIBS = -lpthread
# -g option enables debugging mode
all:
    $(MAKE) -C initialization all
    $(CC) -o $(OUT) $(SOURCE) $(LIBS)
# clean house
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT)
# do a bit of accounting
count:
    wc $(SOURCE) $(HEADER)
```

So with the above makefile I get this error:

```
vasilis@ubuntu:~/Vassilios$ make
make -C initialization all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/vasilis/Vassilios/initialization'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/vasilis/Vassilios/initialization'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Assuming I get it work, I want to move the executable file from the folder "initialization" to the parent folder (Vassilios) and repeat the process for 2 more folders that are located to the parent folder. These folders have different file sources of course. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the makefile in the `initialization` directory, you'll see that it doesn't have an `all` target.

Running `$(MAKE) -C initialization all` tells make: start a new make process with the current working directory as `initialization`, and tell that make process to build `all`.  That make process is failing, because the makefile in `initialization` doesn't know how to build `all`.

Comment: There's no makefile at initialization folder! I access the source files changing the working directory. So, how do I achieve my goal?

Comment: It's not clear what your goal _is_.  If you just want to build some files that live in a different directory, but use this same makefile, then you shouldn't invoke a separate make at all.  Just google around for help on building source files from other directories with make.  There's no need to start another make process in another directory to compile files there.

Comment: Now I get it. I just write makefiles in the folders and call them from the makefile of the parent folder